# How to group data into unequal ranges and assign a value to those ranges in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset that have age variable and that variable has numeric values.

I want to group that variable into unequal ranges such as less that 18, 18-24, 25-34, 35-44, 45-54, 55-64 and 65+.

After grouping the values I want to assign values (say 0,1,2,3,4,5) to each group so that these values are reflected in dataset in a new variable called age group.

Can someone please point me in right direction on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: Try with `?cut` or `?findInterval`.  `cut(df$age, breaks=c(-Inf,18, 24, 34, 44, 54, 65, Inf), labels=FALSE)-1`

Comment: Please consider following values that I want to categorize into groups and then assign values to each group: 
36
73
30
49
47
47
0
46
16
52
0
21
0
57
31
0
40
31
38
0
59
61
48